# Code for extracting 2nd and 3rd neighbor when there is, and ignore when they dont exist

Tags: python, error-handling, cluster-analysis, knn, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to extract the second and third K Nearest Neighbor with this code. I am able to get them when they exist. When they dont exist i get an error like: IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3.

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import pandas as pd

def nn(x):
    nbrs = NearestNeighbors(
        n_neighbors=3, 
        algorithm='auto', 
        metric='euclidean'
    ).fit(x)
    distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(x)
    return distances, indices

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': updated_df['upd_time_code'], 'x': updated_df['x'], 'y': updated_df['y'], 'id': updated_df['id']})

#This has the index of the nearest neighbor in the group, as well as the distance

nns = df.drop('id', 1).groupby('time').apply(lambda x: nn(x.as_matrix()))

groups = df.groupby('time')
nn_rows = []

for i, nn_set in enumerate(nns):
    group = groups.get_group(i)
    print("processing group at: ", group.time)
    for j, tup in enumerate(zip(nn_set[0], nn_set[1])):
        nn_rows.append({'time': i,
                    'id': group.iloc[j]['id'],
                    'nearest_neighbour1': group.iloc[tup[1][1]]['id'],
                    'nearest_neighbour2': group.iloc[tup[1][2]]['id'],
                    'nearest_neighbour3': group.iloc[tup[1][3]]['id']
                    'euclidean_distance1': tup[0][1],
                    'euclidean_distance2': tup[0][2],
                    'euclidean_distance3': tup[0][2]})

nn_df = pd.DataFrame(nn_rows).set_index('time')
nn_df
```

How can I handle the problem of sometimes having neighbors and other times not, can ignore that with adjusting this code?

Comment: Put in `try...except` block and handle the `IndexError` (EAFP) or check the number and then index only of the value is valid (LBYL)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the **fourth** nearest neighbor.

This is a classic array indexing bug in your code that you need to fix.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand. Could you give me a hint where exactly this is happening in the code and how to fix it?

Comment: Because an array of length 3 has values only at positions 0, 1 and 2.